# Inserting a value in array

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, insertion

I am trying to insert a value "item" in a sorted linear array at position "pos"
when i take input in the array using a initialization list the code works fine .. however when i take input using a for loop the code does not work

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
const int size = 10;
int num[size];
int num[size] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}; //a sorted linear array
int item;
int pos;
int i;

/*

for(int a=0;a<size;a++)
{
    cin>>num[a];

}
*/

cout<<"Enter item"<<endl; //insert this item in array
cin>>item;
cout<<"Enter Position To Insert"<<endl;

cin>>pos;

i=size-1;
while(i>=pos)
{
    num[i+1]=num[i];
    i=i-1;
}
num[i+1] = item;

cout<<endl;
cout<<"array after insertion"<<endl;
for(int b=0;b<size;b++)
{

    cout<<num[b]<<endl;
}


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

the for loop causing the problem

```
for(int a=0;a<size;a++)
{
    cin>>num[a];

}
```

Comment: You cannot. Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: i know ! thanks ! but this was a homework problem .. i got it to work but it just doesn't work .. wanted to know what's the problem

Comment: If you have an array of 10 items, and you need to insert 1, then you've overflowed the array (assigning to `num[size]`) with the code you have (you would need to drop the last item from the array).

Comment: Don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: "however when i take input using a for loop the code does not work". What you mean it does not work? It does not compile? It gives the wrong result? "the for loop causing the problem": What is the problem with it? What do you expect and what do you get? Please be more precise. What _exactly_ is the problem?

Comment: when i use initializer list the insertion occurs at the particular position .. when i use for loop the program does not insert a value in the array at particular position

Comment: @MuhammadUmarTariq So the `for` loop does not work because you did not write the `for` loop in a way that it inserts the values in a sorted order? So try to write that code then ask questions about why your attempt is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code snippet

```
i=size-1;
while(i>=pos)
{
    num[i+1]=num[i];
    i=i-1;
}
num[i+1] = item;
```

is wrong. First of all `pos` can be greater than or equal to `size` In this case none element should be inserted in the array. However according to the last statement of the code snippet

```
num[i+1] = item;
```

`num[size]` will be asssigned with `item`.

Again within the loop for initial value of i equal to `size - 1` there is an attempt to assign `num[size]` element

```
    num[i+1]=num[i];
```

The code snippet can be rewritten for example the following way

```
if ( pos < size )
{
    i = size;

    while ( --i != pos ) num[i] = num[i-1];

    num[i] = item;
}
```